# The sign of multiplicative inverse modulo p

Tags: number-theory, inverse

Let $p$ be a sufficiently large prime number. Then we can define uniquely a function $\varepsilon: \{1,\ldots,\frac{1}{2}(p-1)\} \to \{-1,+1\}$ and a permutation $\sigma$ of $\{1,\ldots,\frac{1}{2}(p-1)\}$ such that $\varepsilon(x)\sigma(x)$ is the multiplicative inverse of $x$ modulo $p$, for each $x=1,\ldots,\frac{1}{2}(p-1)$.

**Question.** Is it true that, "on average", $\varepsilon$ takes half of the times value $+1$ and half of the times value $-1$?

Comment: To confirm that I have understood: the question is if about a half of the elements of $\{1,2,\ldots,\frac12(p-1)\}$ have their inverses in the set $\{\frac12(p+1),\ldots,p-1\}$. Correct? Have you empirical evidence, for example, from a little computer program?

Comment: Yes, correct; actually no, I don't have empirical evidences; it is just a curiosity since I could not find much works related to the distribution of multiplicative inverses

Comment: See [here](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/243003494_The_distribution_of_patterns_of_inverses_modulo_a_prime) and  [here](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.mmj/1213972400) and [here](http://www.math.uiuc.edu/~ford/wwwpapers/fksy.pdf) for some related work.